# Application crashes when I use an onChange modifier on a PresentationDetent

Tags: swiftui

Below is a sample view that will crash.

If I remove the `onChange` handler everything works fine, of course. It appears that simply watching the `PresentationDetent` type is causing this.

This [PresentationDetent type](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/presentationdetent) does conform to `Equatable` as mentioned in the [onChange(of:initial:_:) documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scene/onchange(of:initial:_:)-7r9vn).

Has anyone bumped into this? Maybe there is a better way to take an action once a sheet-size has changed?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentViewSheetDetents: View {
    @State private var sheetDetent = PresentationDetent.medium
    @State private var isPresented = true

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented) {
                Text("Oh, hi!")
                    .presentationDetents(
                        [.medium, .large],
                        selection: $sheetDetent
                    )
            }
        .onChange(of: sheetDetent) {
            print("Detent changed")
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentViewSheetDetents()
}
```

Comment: You are missing a `.` before `onChange`

Comment: OH GOODNESS! @jnpdx FTW! It seems that `onChange` is not a compiler warning or error. adding the `.` was all that was needed. Sorry for the noise. Thanks @jnpdx

Comment: Yeah, it's not an error because it's valid to call it on `self` (which is a `View`), but it leads to recursion.